# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java when using split

Tags: java, string, split, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to read file and split its line to get some context(Computer Name and Date), the code gives few lines of outputs then gives the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at FILE_MAIN.getComputerName(FILE_MAIN.java:34)
        at FILE_MAIN.readFiles(FILE_MAIN.java:24)
        at FILE_MAIN.main(FILE_MAIN.java:12)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FILE_MAIN
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File folder = new File("folderName/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
        {
            readFiles(listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
    public static void readFiles(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        FileReader dataFile = new FileReader("yukt/"+fileName);
        try (Scanner FileRead = new Scanner(dataFile)) 
        {
            while (FileRead.hasNextLine() && FileRead.nextLine().isEmpty()==false)
            {
                String[] split;
                String line = FileRead.nextLine();
                split = line.split("\\|",-1);
                String computerName=getComputerName(split[0]);
                System.out.println(computerName);
            }      
        }
    }
    public static String getComputerName(String splited)
    {
        String[] split1;
        String[] split2;
        split1=splited.split("\\:",-1);
        split2=split1[1].split("\\ ",-1);
        return("a");
    }
    public static String getDate(String splited)
    {
        String[] split1=splited.split("\\(",-1);
        String[] split2=split1[1].split("\\ ",-1);
        return(split2[0]);
    }
}
```

The main function gets names of the files in a folder, and passes each file to the readFiles function where each line is split into 3 parts by a delimeter(|) and parts are send to getComputerName and getDate function which returns its values after further splitting the strings.

Here is an example of a line of the file, all the lines are similar to this:

```
[CD8C] ComputerName:NITIN UserID:GO ankurjain Station 9900  LanId: | (11/24 19:50:30) | Client is disconnected from agent.
```

Comment: Add an example-input to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no protection for `split1` containing a single element:

```
split1=splited.split("\\:",-1);
split2=split1[1].split("\\ ",-1); // Accesses second element of split1
```

Add protection and decide if it is an error for there to be no `:` in the input string or just use whole string if no `:`:

```
split1=splited.split("\\:",-1);
if (split1.length > 1)
{
    split2=split1[1].split("\\ ",-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
split1=splited.split("\\:",-1);
split2=split1[1].split("\\ ",-1);
```

split1 must not be doing what you think.
i.e. it is not splitting, cos split1[1] is not valid.

You should really check the result of the first split before trying to use it's results.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where I had to check weather string sub part contains given string or not. But String in question had many variation. Instead of using if loop I used ternary operator -

```
StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase("Test String",
                    ("split me".split(":").length > 1)
                        ? "split me".split(":")[1] : "Can't split")
```

Answer (score -1):

`split2=split1[1]` gives you `java.lang.`[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)`: 1` the error. The Array does not have 2 elements so index on 1 will throw an error.

You could add a check to make sure it has atleast 2 elements by putting the assignement in a if statement

```
if (split1.lenght > 1){
  split2=split1[1].split("\\ ",-1);
}
```

Comment: Assume we have this string String str="call   foo" splitting this string based on "\t" will result in two separated values, but the str.length will not be greater than 1. therefore your answer, I think, will not work correctly.